# Insert text into line if that line doesn't contain another string using sed

Tags: regex, bash, sed

I am merging a number of text files on a linux server but the lines in some differ slightly and I need to unify them.

For example some files will have line like

```
id='1244' group='american' name='fred',american
```

Other files will be like

```
id='2345' name='frank', english
```

finally others will be like

```
id='7897' group='' name='maria',scottish
```

what I need to do is, if group='' or group is not in the string at all I need to add it somewhere before the comma setting it to the text after the comma so in the 2nd example above the line would become:

```
id='2345' name='frank' group='english',english
```

and the same in the last example which would become

```
id='7897' name='maria' group='scottish',scottish
```

This is going into a bash script. I can't actually delete the line and add to the end of the file as it relates to the following line.

I've used the following:

```
sed -i.bak 's#group=""##' file
```

which deletes the group="" string so the lines will either contain group='something' or wont contain it at all and that works

Then I tried to add the group if it doesn't exist using the following:

```
sed -i.bak '/group/! s#,(.*$)#group="\1",\1#' file
```

but that throws up the error

```
sed: -e expression #1, char 38: invalid reference \1 on `s' command's RHS
```

**EDIT** by Ed Morton to create a single sample input file and expected output:

Sample Input:

```
id='1244' group='american' name='fred',american
foo
id='2345' name='frank', english
bar
id='7897' group='' name='maria',scottish
```

Expected Output:

```
id='1244' group='american' name='fred',american
foo
id='2345' name='frank' group='english',english
bar
id='7897' name='maria' group='scottish',scottish
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? Let's see some code :-)

Comment: Sorry I've edited my question to show what I have tried.

Comment: In BRE (Basic Regular Expression) syntax, the default pattern syntax for sed, parenthesis for a capture group have to be escaped: `\(.*$\)` otherwise, they are seen as literal characters.

Comment: I edited your question to try to provide 1 sample input file and the expected output given that input. If it's wrong then please fix it. A bunch of separate input lines, some with the expected output, some without, and none of it with the context of surrounding lines isn't nearly as useful as one concrete example with context.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
sed -r "
    /group=''/ s///                                   # group is empty, remove it
    /group=/!  s/,[[:blank:]]*(.+)/ group='\\1',\\1/  # group is missing, add it
" file
```

```
id='1244' group='american' name='fred',american
foo
id='2345' name='frank' group='english',english
bar
id='7897'  name='maria' group='scottish',scottish
```

The foo and bar lines are untouched because the s/// command did not match a comma followed by characters.

Comment: This has pointed me in the right direction, it appears to be doing exactly as described but the EOL appears to be messing it up. I'm getting output like 
id='7897'  name='maria' group='scottish
so missing the last ' around the group and the text from comma onwards

Comment: could my latest issue be because I already use sed -i -e "s/^M//g" on the files?#

Comment: Kind of sounds like stay carriage returns. `s/\r$//`

Comment: With carriage returns, I expect you see the end of the line overwriting the start of the line: `',scottish name='maria' group='scottish`

Answer (score 1):

something like

```
sed  '
    /^[^,]*group[^,]*,/ ! {
        s/, *\(.*\)/ group='\''\1'\'', \1/
    }
    /^[^,]*group='\'\''/ {
        s/group='\'\''\([^,]*\), *\(.*\)/group='\''\2'\''\1, \2/
    }
'
```

Answer (score 0):

This GNU `awk` may help:

```
awk -v sq="'" '
  BEGIN{RS="[ ,\n]+"; FS="="; found=0}
  $1=="group"{
    if($2==sq sq) 
      {next}
    else
      {found=1}
  }
  NF>1{
    printf "%s=%s ",$1,$2
  }
  NF==1{
    if(!found)
      {printf "group=%s",$1}
    print ","$1
    found=0
  }
' file
```

The script relies on the record separator `RS` which is set to get all `key='value'` pairs.

If the key `group` isn't found or is empty, it is printed when reaching a record with only one field.

Note that the variable `sq` holds the single quote character and is used to detect empty `group` field.

Answer (score 0):

Sed can be pretty ugly. And your data format appears to be somewhat inconsistent. This MIGHT work for you:

```
$ sed -e "/group='[a-z]/b e" -e "s/group='' *//" -e "s/,\([a-z]*\)$/ group='\1', /" -e ':e' input.txt
```

Broken out for easier reading, here's what we're doing:

- `/group='[a-z]/b e` - If the line contains a valid `group`, branch to the end.
- `s/group='' *//` - Remove any empty group,
- `s/,\([a-z]*\)$/ group='\1', /` - add a new group based on your specs
- `:e` - branch label for the first command.
- And then the default action is to print the line.

I really don't like manipulating data this way. It's prone to error, and you'll be further ahead reading this data into something that accurately stores its data structure, then prints the data according to a new structure. A more robust solution would likely be tied directly to whatever is producing or consuming this data, and would not sit in the middle like this.